# Remix. Different contract behavior on Javascript VM and Injected Web3

Tags: web3js, remix, javascript-vm

The following basic contract does not have the same behavior when
deployed on `Javascript VM` and on `Injected Web3`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage {

    uint number; 
    
    function store(uint num) public{
        require(num>10,"failure");
        number = num;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint){ 
        return number;
    }

}
```

When deployed on the `Javascript VM`:

- the requirement fails when `store` is given a number smaller or equal to 10
- the output of the `retrieve` function is shown (thanks to the
  view annotation)

When deployed on the `Injected Web3` (tried on Rosten and Kovan):

- the requirement does not fail when `store` is given a number
  smaller or equal to 10
- the output of the `retrieve` function is always `-`.

[image]

On `Injected Web` I have the feeling that, even if transactions or
calls are claimed to be successful, the contract was not even run!

Any guess?

Comment: I tried to verify it through Etherscan and it is OK. Besides, I manage to call it through [Etherscan write tab](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x496bc9cdf8dfe87ec9b6718ec78a7ca06dd321c7#writeContract) and if I call it with a number smaller or equal to 10 it fails, as expected. Thus I think that it is Remix output which is bugged.

Comment: Changing ```public``` to ```external``` in the above code solves the problem. Does this makes sense?